# Using Sqlite how to maintain mailing service in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, sqlite, email, visual-studio-2013, windows-phone-8.1

I created a login page and registration page in windows phone 8.1 app using sqlite database. When I login through the values from database how to create a mail system similar to normal mailing services like gmail using sqlite database.

(or)

How to save particular user data with respect to the user logged in. When the user login to the mainpage his data should be displayed.

Please answer the above both questions.

I successfully created login and registration page and I can insert values to the database. After navigating to the new page what should I code in order to show the data of the logged in user
[image]

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<Register>();
    }
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);
        await con.CreateTableAsync<Register>();
        Register m = new Register();

        m.Name = text_reg.Text;
        m.Password = text_password.Password;
        string r = "";
        if (radio_male.IsChecked == true)
        {
            r = "Male";

        }
        else
        {
            r = "Female";

        }
        m.Gender = r;
        m.State = ((ComboBoxItem)combo_box.SelectedItem).Content.ToString();


        await con.InsertAsync(m);

        MessageDialog md = new MessageDialog("success");
        await md.ShowAsync();
    }

    private async void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Windows.Storage.ApplicationDataContainer data = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;
        data.Values["check"] = text_reg.Text;
        var dbpath = ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path + "/ebook.db";
        var con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbpath);

        Register t = new Register();
        string query = string.Format("select Name,Password from Register where Name='{0}' and Password='{1}'", text_user.Text, text_pass.Password);
        List<Register> mylist = await con.QueryAsync<Register>(query);
        if (mylist.Count == 1)
        {
            t = mylist[0];
        }

        if (t.Name == text_user.Text && t.Password == text_pass.Password)
        {

            this.Frame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage));
        }
        else
        {
            var messagedialog = new MessageDialog("Unsuccessful").ShowAsync();
        }
    }
```

The above code runs successfully. After navigating to next page(i.e MainPage) how to show the particular data

Answer (score 0):

Ok, the mailing system part of your question I couldn't fully understand it.
as for the second part, you have many options.

1. Use a static property that will hold `t` and reuse it in every page in your app if you want.
2. Use a ViewModel to hold any values you want to reuse across your app.
3. Write whatever values you want to a Temp file within your app scope/domain

The easiest way is option 1.
just add `public static Register CurrentUser { get; set; };` to your App.xaml.cs.

and you can access this variable via `App.CurrentUser.Name` and `App.CurrentUser.Password`

and don't forget to set CurrentUser before your navigation to main Page.

```
App.CurrentUser = t;
```